# Lucene.NET query + highlighting

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, umbraco

I am using Umbraco and came across Lucene. I found a lot of code and articles on Lucene, but I still can't build an acceptable search.

I have a number of fields to search from, eg. "nodeName" and "bodyText"

What I need:

- When I search for "men shoes", it should only return results that have both "men" and "shoes", but also return a page where the nodeName only has "shoes" and the bodyText only has "men".
- When I search for "shoes", I want results containing "shoe" or "shoes." but not "hoes" if possible
- Boost the nodeName field
- Get a snippet of bodyText that contains the matched word(s)
- Highlight the matched words on both the page name and the snippet of the bodyText

Has anyone ever done this?

Comment: Yes Lucene does all you need and *much* more. However, since you appear to be a newbie, I'd recommend using Apache Solr (which is a search server built around Lucene and offers many features out of the box, without having to tinker with the innards.

Comment: Thanks. How do I use that with Umbraco...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code by Jonathan Lathigee works, it's the most google-like I could find so far

http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/19329-Search-multiple-fields-for-multiple-terms-with-examine?p=0

Answer (score 1):

This might get you started.

```
var manager = ExamineManager.Instance;
var searcher = manager.SearchProviderCollection["YOURSearcher"];
var query = manager.SearchProviderCollection["YOURSearcher"].CreateSearchCriteria(BooleanOperation.Or)
   .Field("nodeName", keywords.Boost(10))
   .Or().Field("nodeName", keywords.Fuzzy())
   .Or().Field("bodyContent", keywords.Boost(5))
   .Or().Field("otherField", keywords.Boost(3));
var results = searcher.Search(query.Compile());
```

Comment: Thanks Kieran! What is keywords? It's not string is it? Because string doesn't have Boost method.

Comment: It is an extension to string, you must add using Examine.LuceneEngine.SearchCriteria;

Comment: When I search for multiple words it never returns any results